# Magento 2.1 Product url shows two times suffix

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, migration, magento2-migration-tool, product-urls

My store product url shows two times .html as suffix like below
http://localhost/m2migration/canape-chesterfield-assise-capitonnee-cuir.html.html

This issue arised after ubertheme migration.

Can you please tell me how can i resolve it?

I am using Magento 2.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We have this problem too.

Comment: @Webninja, we didn't find the solution but just dump url table and find and replace .html.html with .html and import it again.It works fine now in our store. Its not a proper solution but no one is answering our query.

Answer (score 0):

try to update database value for url_rewrite

```
UPDATE url_rewrite 
SET request_path = CONCAT(LEFT(request_path, CHAR_LENGTH(request_path) -10), '.html')
WHERE request_path LIKE '%.html.html';


UPDATE catalog_category_entity_varchar SET value = REPLACE(value, '/', '') WHERE attribute_id = 118;

UPDATE catalog_category_entity_varchar SET value = REPLACE(value, '/', '') WHERE attribute_id = 120;
```

The following command will help you in removing double .html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:-

1. Export your products.
2. remove unexpected .html string from url_key save
3. Import correct CSV, with only sku,url_key columns.